# Regular expression to match +-*/ any of these characters just once. In Java

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make a calculator in android with Java. Where I need to split the strings, to separate the digits and operands. Then, I will do the necessary operations with the digits. I need a regular expression to get it done.
I have tried this:

```
String[] numbers = screenText.split("[+\-/*]";
```

I am getting an error: Illegal character range.

Comment: Did you try anything yet? If not, why?

Comment: I have tried and failed miserably. That's why I am here.

Comment: Well, you should still show what you've tried so far. That will make it easier to help you in a way that's easier understand at your current knowledge level. :)

Comment: If you know the answer, please give the answer,

Comment: @tanvirgeek I know you just want answers, but you can't barge in and make demands from people here. It's easier to help when we've seen what you've tried

Comment: I tried this [+-*/] then I got an error which is: unexpected range. See I have really tried.. :)

Comment: `-` is a special character in regex (used for specifying ranges of characters). You have to escape it with a backslash `\-`

Comment: I have given one backslash, then I got an error. Then I gave two backslashes, then its ok. I dont know why.

Comment: All of this information (the code that you tried, and the exact error messages you got) should be part of your question.

Comment: Well, since backslash is the escape character for Java strings as well you need 2 for one in the regex, i.e. `"[+\\-*/]"` for the epxression `[+\-*/]`. However, that expression alone doesn't help much, we'd also need to see how you tried to apply it. From your description it _seems_ as if you want to preserve the operators, e.g. `3+5` should be split into `3`, `+`, `5` - is that correct?

Comment: I gave the necessary info that you had mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regular expression to split the operand is `"[+\\-/*]"` but you probably looking for something like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LL_grammar

Comment: I needed to give two backslashes to make it work.

Comment: @tanvirgeek yes, if you will place it in `"string"` literal you have to escape the `\\`.